# How to launch sshuttle without superuser pwd prompt

Tags: linux, automation

I love the [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) "poor man's VPN", however, having it require me to enter superuser pwd when launching each time makes my life sad.

Is there a way I can either elevate the script or modify it in a way so that it can launch unattended?

In this scenario, the operating system being used is a Debian derivative.

Comment: See [this example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Shutting_Down_From_The_Console_Without_A_Password) for how you can use sudo to run a particular set of commands as root with no password prompt. Should be easily adapted to your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look on `ps` output when you prompted with sudo password. Here the output of this command when `sshuttle` was executed

```
ps auxwww |grep sud
root      3504  0.1  0.0 231384  7516 pts/1    S+   18:36   0:00 sudo -p [local sudo] Password:  /usr/bin/python /usr/share/sshuttle/main.py /usr/bin/python -v --firewall 12300 0
```

So you need to put above command to `/etc/sudoers` to grant you sudo power without password when you launch `sshuttle`.

```
# edit sudoers safely
sudo visudo
```

And put these lines

```
Cmnd_Alias SSHUTTLE = /usr/bin/python /usr/share/sshuttle/main.py /usr/bin/python -v --firewall 12300 0

username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SSHUTTLE
```

Comment: One more thing: if you use a passphrase-protected private key stored in the local machine's root account to authenticate to the remote box, you may still get a prompt to `Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa'`.  On my Ubuntu desktop (should work on other desktops which use gnome-keyring) I managed to bypass this prompt by adding the following to my `sudoers`entry: `Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY HOME GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`. Voilà, no more password prompts!

Comment: I am not sudoer, so how can I access those files without sudo? 
Do you have any practical way to solve it?
not root access, no sudo access, can I use sshuttle?

Answer (score 6):

According to [official instructions](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#sudoers-file):

> sshuttle --sudoers --sudoers-user <your_username>

Comment: Wherein I discovered the version of sshuttle on Ubuntu is really outdated and doesn't support this command.